# Moving a drive with a Perforce workspace from one computer to another

Tags: perforce

I have a new computer at work, and I want to move a disk from my old computer to my new one. The disk has Perforce workspaces on it. I would like to be able to use them from the new computer rather than erasing those directories and creating new workspaces, but I have seen some indications that they may be tied to the individual computer.  What steps are needed to make this move? Google has so far not led me to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Move the disk.
2. Update your client specs (`p4 client` in the CLI, or `Edit Workspace...` in P4V):

   - `Root:` update this to reflect the new drive letter (if applicable)
   - `Host:` update this to reflect the host name of the new computer

That's all you need to do.

This is the *one* situation in which it makes sense to edit the `Host` field of an existing client spec (when the physical workspace itself, i.e. the disk, is now associated with a different client host).